# Tomcat: how to avoid per session thread

Tags: multithreading, tomcat

I'm debugging a web-app, I saw that when I send multiple requests from the same browser (same session) Tomcat serialize these requests and serve them syncronously.
If I try with many different browsers, I got real concurrent execution.

How to configure Tomcat to avoid synchronous processing for the same session?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that it's tomcat doing this? It might be your browser using the same connections. It might also be your browser requesting the "page" first (which you then debug) and only starting to receive additional resources (css, images, etc) later. Once the page is there, referencing all the other resources, the other resources might be loaded concurrently through many different requests.

You might want to do some packet-sniffing, e.g. check with wireshark how many connection the browser opens while you're debugging your application.

Comment: Yes, maybe can be my browser... i will try to check it, but I'm working with json-only pages, so it can't be related to other resources (img, css and so on).